# How to run VBScript in .net core or .net standard project?

Tags: vbscript, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

i know it`s dead-end and stupid idea, but still... 
Do you know any nuget or workaround ways to run VBScript within .Net Core or .Net Standard projects?

I`ve tried to use ClearScript.V8 nuget (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClearScript.V8/) from Microsoft. It does not support .net standard 2.0 at all.

I would appreciate for any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried MSScriptControl?

Comment: Looks like MSScriptControl is obsolete as well and it does require System.Web.UI which is not appropriate for my case.

Comment: I'm using the one from Interop.MSScriptControl.dll, which I don't think is the same as the Scriptcontrol from System.Web.UI. I use it to execute scripts (and parts of scripts) in a C# application.