# Deserialize non xml or json response from API

Tags: vb.net, serialization

Been trying to figure out if there is a way to deserialize this object below. the problem is the api returns the data in this format. There seems to be an object here called Info that is listof()..

> `"found=23" & vbCrLf & "info[0].Channel=0" & vbCrLf & "info[0].EndTime=2020-05-11 00:59:59" & vbCrLf & "info[0].EnteredSubtotal=0" & vbCrLf & "info[0].ExitedSubtotal=0" & vbCrLf & "info[0].RuleName=NumberStat" & vbCrLf & "info[0].StartTime=2020-05-11 00:00:00" & vbCrLf & "info[1].Channel=0" & vbCrLf & "info[1].EndTime=2020-05-11 01:59:59" & vbCrLf & "info[1].EnteredSubtotal=0" & vbCrLf & "info[1].ExitedSubtotal=0" & vbCrLf & "info[1].RuleName=NumberStat" & vbCrLf & "info[1].StartTime=2020-05-11 01:00:00" & vbCrLf & "info[2].Channel=0" & vbCrLf & "info[2].EndTime=2020-05-11 02:59:59" & vbCrLf & "info[2].EnteredSubtotal=0" & vbCrLf & "info[2].ExitedSubtotal=0" & vbCrLf & "info[2].RuleName=NumberStat" & vbCrLf & "info[2].StartTime=2020-05-11 02:00:00" & vbCrLf & "info[3].Channel=0" & vbCrLf & "info[3].EndTime=2020-05-11 03:59:59" & vbCrLf & "info[3].EnteredSubtotal=0" & vbCrLf & "info[3].ExitedSubtotal=0" & vbCrLf & "info[3].RuleName=NumberStat" & vbCrLf & "info[3].StartTime=2020-05-11 03:00:00" & vbCrLf & "info`

Thanks in advance for any ideas here.

Comment: Are you sure that the API doesn't allow a different format? It looks like a weird way to return data objects. Anyway, you should post the actual string you receive: this one is taken directly from the string visualizer. Open it in the Text visualizer, so all the `vbCrLf` and double quotes won't be there.

Comment: Anyway, you could try to parse it as `info\[(\d+)\].(\w+)=(\S+\s*[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}]*)` (using Regex.Matches): in Group(1) you have the object indexer, in Group(2) the Property Name and in Group(3) the property value.

Comment: Looks like you need binary serialization and definition of `class info {  Channel, 
EndTime, EnteredSubtotal, ExitedSubtotal, RuleName, StartTime }`. But what you see is just a string and not some object. What you see is text representation of array of class `info`. You can binary serialize and retrieve and deserialize it. Or you can write a parser. In fact, @Jimi seems got it for you

Comment: thanks Everyone jimi and T.S an combination of the your suggestions might work. Ramdom Guy is correct if you right the output the window it all nicely formatted like below. The API where the data comes from is a people counting camera. I looked every where to see where i can change the response i get from the API to json or xml. Emailed the company with no response.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is VBscript.

vbCrLf means new line so:

```
"found=23" 
 "info[0].Channel=0" 
 "info[0].EndTime=2020-05-11 00:59:59" 
 "info[0].EnteredSubtotal=0" 
 "info[0].ExitedSubtotal=0" 
 "info[0].RuleName=NumberStat" 
 "info[0].StartTime=2020-05-11 00:00:00" 
 "info[1].Channel=0" 
 "info[1].EndTime=2020-05-11 01:59:59" 
 "info[1].EnteredSubtotal=0" 
 "info[1].ExitedSubtotal=0" 
 "info[1].RuleName=NumberStat" 
 "info[1].StartTime=2020-05-11 01:00:00" 
 "info[2].Channel=0" 
 "info[2].EndTime=2020-05-11 02:59:59" 
 "info[2].EnteredSubtotal=0" 
 "info[2].ExitedSubtotal=0" 
 "info[2].RuleName=NumberStat" 
 "info[2].StartTime=2020-05-11 02:00:00" 
 "info[3].Channel=0" 
 "info[3].EndTime=2020-05-11 03:59:59" 
 "info[3].EnteredSubtotal=0" 
 "info[3].ExitedSubtotal=0" 
 "info[3].RuleName=NumberStat" 
 "info[3].StartTime=2020-05-11 03:00:00"
```

I think this might be useful:
[How to run VBScript in .net core or .net standard project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020687/how-to-run-vbscript-in-net-core-or-net-standard-project)

Comment: Not sure what VBScript has to do with this, the extra formatting you've done in my mind at least makes this quite obvious an array of info objects.  No idea why the OP would need to run vb script to deserialize it

Comment: Thanks. Random Guy has it nicely formatted so same way it gets formatted when i write the response to the output window. for some reason the raw data has all that vb formatting.